# how to get last n indices in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following dataframe:

```
        volume
index
 1        65
 1        55
 2        44
 2        56
 3        46
 3        75
 4        64
 4        64
```

when i put the code  `df.iloc[-2:]`
.it only shows the last two rows of my dataframe. example:

```
        volume
index
 4        64
 4        64
```

---

i want to get the last two indices with the result below

```
        volume
index
 3        46
 3        75
 4        64
 4        64
```

how do i go about it?

Comment: note that i want to get the last n indices of any dataframe... not just ```df.iloc[-4:]```

Comment: ``df.loc[df.index.isin(df.index.unique()[-2:])]``?

Answer (score 5):

You can slice the index after getting the unique values, then use `Series.isin`:

```
df[df.index.isin(df.index.unique()[-2:])]
```

Or

```
df.loc[df.index.unique()[-2:]]
```

```
       volume
index        
3          46
3          75
4          64
4          64
```